# How to disable hints in Dev C++?

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++, hints, type-hinting

I have Bloodshed Dev C++ 4.9.9.2.

Every time I stop typing for a second this hint pops up and I can't see a thing what I'm typing! I have a feeling that it waits for a most unsuitable moment to pop up. Then it disappears in 2 secs, or, sometimes, whenever it wants.

[image: dev c plus plus hint tooltip]

Is there a way to disable it? (haven't found one in the settings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used Dev-C++, but from searching on the Net I found two links:

- http://www.bloodshed.net/dev/NEWS.txt
- http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/26479-dev-c-pauses-when-i-type-or-next-to-a-class/

In the first, it says that in version 4.9.5.5 they added an option for **mouse** hints disabling - maybe it will work for keyboard, too.

In the second link, they say disabling "class browsing" will work for a similar issue - might not be what you want (as it probably disables everything), but give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

it confused me too. So when i got the answer, i come here. here is the answer.
On the top of the IDE, choose the 'tools', next 'editor options', then find the checked box 'show editor hints'. uncheck it. done. Hope this helpful.